# Secondary forms of revenue as a sound designer

Tags: business, work, projects, income

I hope that, like me, you're all enjoying the new SSD format. I have another question about sales pipelines that I hope you might be able to help me with.

When the dedicated sound design projects aren't coming in thick and fast, what other avenues do you guys explore that have cross-transferable sound design skills, if any?

For example, I do a little freelance live sound engineering when I get a chance, as well as some DJing too. I find a lot of the skills I've picked up through my education and experience of sound design come in handy here.

Are there opportunities for other forms of audio editing or general technical work available? What about things like lecturing or writing for trade publications? As I say, I'm curious if there's anything I haven't considered at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from strictly "audio production work":

• Selling sound effects and sound effects or sample libraries
• Preset design for musical instrument or audio effects plug-in developers
• Marketing for musical instrument and audio gear manufacturers
• Renting recording gear and studio facilities
• Acoustical consultation and studio design/building (but you need to be versed in acoustics to do this)
• Music technology sales work
• Writing for music/audio magazines or web publications (but you should have some knowledge about journalism)
• Teaching/lecturing (doable as a private practitioner, but for public institutions as well as trade shows or symposiums need to be a "recognized professional" or pass the "job interview" or paper/application filtering in other ways. Good pedagogical and conversational skills as well obviously. In universities a PhD in the subject domain is mandatory for full-time teaching.).